# How can we read error logs that are contained in a website through javascript in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I need a functionality in my extension to collect the error logs from a website. How can I do that using javascript?

Comment: You can intercept `console` methods in a [page-level script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9517879). You can also listen to `'error'` event on `window` (possibly also inside a page-level script).

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through the [welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.